# What did NASA Vehicle Assembly Building's "weather" look like? Did it really have clouds? Did it rain?

Tags: nasa, history, weather, vehicle-assembly-building

Comments below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/45052/12102) to *Would there be snow, rain, fog or clouds in a deep, sealed, subsurface cavern on the Moon if water were present?* point out that the NASA [Vehicle Assembly Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Assembly_Building) originally had "weather" and the Wikipedia article confirms that something like this happened before a moisture reduction system (read "giant dehumidifier") was added.

**Question:** Before that was added, what did the so-called "weather" look like? Did it really have clouds? Did it rain?

Comment: I don't have a reference so not writing an answer, but in my experience "weather" is an exaggeration. Humidity, enough for condensation to form. Maybe some mist if you squint.